# How we make the filter for fornt end user

Tags: filters, search

I develope a filter for posts so that when any user come to my site they can filter the posts on the base of `cities/state`.
So when i store the posts i just store the cities name as a `post-meta` tag in the site. The code i am using for adding the `post-meta` tag is

```
add_post_meta($post_id, 'post_state' , $state, true);
```

The html which generating the names of the cities in the form of checkbox is here

```
for(x in state_arr){
    jQuery('#state_div').append('<label><input type="checkbox" name="stateName['+ state_arr[x] +']" id="" value="'+ state_arr[x] +'" >' + state_arr[x] + '</label');
}
```

So i pass the name as `array`.

And the code i am using for filter is here

```
<?php
if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'sortbydestination' ) :
$stateName = $_POST['stateName'];
foreach($stateName as $key => $stN) 
{
   $citynames = $stN . ","; 
}
unset($_POST);
endif;

?>
```

And the argument which i pass to the query is look like this

```
$args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 30,
            'paged' => $paged, 
            'post_type' => 'post', 
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'meta_query' => array(
                            'key' => 'post_state',
                            'value' => array($citynames )

                            ) 
            );
```

I want to know one thing. Here i in query the `value` need one value but i have to pass multiple valuse to compare and find the result so how can i do that.

Comment: The problem in this code is after code i unset the post `unset($_POST);`. So i just simply remove it and my code is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is on the meta_query you need to add an other argument like

```
'compare' => '='
```

you can also use relation.

I suggest you try the query first.

Comment: Nops this is not an issue. By default it compare both `key` and `values`.

Comment: why not use ajax?

Comment: I have no idea how to use it. The main concern here is. Wehter i am passing the value in correct way or not.

Answer (score 0):

Meta query expects nested arrays, even if you only have one query. You will have to pass nested array to meta_query as following :

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 30,
        'paged' => $paged, 
        'post_type' => 'post', 
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_query' => array(  array(
                        'key' => 'post_state',
                        'value' => array($citynames )
                              )
                        ) 
        );
```

For more information see [this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

Comment: tell me one thing. `$citynames` have multiple values here. so this meta_query work for multiple values or not. because it still showing me all results. Don't no why. Any solution for that

Comment: I find the problem finally. Thanks all of you who help me.

Comment: @Adi Now either post your own solution here and mark it as answer two days later, or check if any of those answers were the solution and in case this is true, mark them as solution. Thanks.